# Integrate ArcTanh or ArcTan

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm confused with this integral sometimes Mathematica gave me ArcTanh and ArcTan?!!

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a x^2-b}+c x} \, dx$$

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the exact Mathematica codes you're using.

Comment: Clear["Global`*"]
f = Integrate[1/(
  Sqrt[(a + b^2/(4 c^2)) x^2 - (1 - 2/(3 c))] + (b/(2 c) x)), x]
expr1 = (f /. x -> R) - (f /. x -> 1);
FullSimplify[expr1, Assumptions -> {{x > 0, a > 0, b > 0, c > 1}}]

Comment: not clear what is the question. What exactly is the problem? what do you mean by `sometimes Mathematica gave me ArcTanh and ArcTan` ?

Comment: Just compare the solution for these two integrals :

f = Integrate[1/(Sqrt[a x^2 - b] + c x), x]



Clear["Global`*"]
f = Integrate[1/(
  Sqrt[(a + b^2/(4 c^2)) x^2 - (1 - 2/(3 c))] + (b/(2 c) x)), x]
expr1 = (f /. x -> R) - (f /. x -> 1);
FullSimplify[expr1, Assumptions -> {{x > 0, a > 0, b > 0, c > 1}}]

Comment: They are basically the same but first is ArcTanh and second ArcTan

Comment: Do be careful about doing indefinite integrals and then substituting in the bounds, as you propose in your comment.  This does not always yield the correct result.  See [this blog post](https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/) for the reasons why.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing surprising because they are closely connected

```
Simplify[ArcTanh[I x] - I ArcTan[x], Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]
(* 0 *)
```

One form may be preferred over the other in order to have a function of the real argument.

Comment: For example, how can I include this assumption on this integral? 

Assumptions -> {x>0, 0<a <1, 0< b <1, 0< c <1}]

Comment: I agree with you, but the correct solution should be ArcTan and I don't know how to find that part which is produced the AracTanh. It means where is the complex part.

Comment: @user199315 There are some answers here, for instance, the one using Rubi package.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
f = Integrate[ 1/(Sqrt[(a + b^2/(4 c^2)) x^2 - (1 -2/(3 c))] + (b/(2 c) x))
, {x,1, a}, Assumptions -> { a > 1, b > 0, c > 1}]
```

and Mathematica evaluates an unique solution

```
    (*(1/(4 a c))(-2 b ArcTanh[(a b)/Sqrt[a^2 b^2 + (8 c)/3 + 4 (-1 + a^3) c^2]] +2 b ArcTanh[b/Sqrt[b^2 + 4/3 c (2 + 3 (-1 + a)c)]] + 
b Log[2 + 3 (-1 + a) c] - b Log[2 + 3 (-1 +a^3) c] +2 Sqrt[b^2 + 4 a c^2]Log[3 a b^2 + 12 a^2 c^2 + 
Sqrt[3] Sqrt[(b^2 + 4 a c^2) (3 a^2 b^2 + 4(2 - 3 c) c +12 a^3 c^2)]] - 
2 Sqrt[b^2 + 4 a c^2]Log[3 b^2 + 12 a c^2 +Sqrt[3] Sqrt[(b^2 + 4 a c^2) (3 b^2 + 4 c (2+ 3 (-1 + a) c))]])*)
```

Comment: As you see here your solution has ArcTanh term but if you just put this integral which is basically the same :

Clear["Global`*"]
f = Integrate[1/(
  Sqrt[(a + b^2/(4 c^2)) x^2 - (1 - 2/(3 c))] + (b/(2 c) x)), x]
expr1 = (f /. x -> R) - (f /. x -> 1);
FullSimplify[expr1, Assumptions -> {{x > 0, a > 0, b > 0, c > 1}}]

You will have ArcTan ?????!!!!!!!!

Comment: No it isn't the same! Your substitution is only allowed, if no singularity exists inside the intergation range!

Answer (score 0):

Rubi does the job:

```
Get["Rubi`"]; Int[1/(Sqrt[(a + b^2/(4 c^2)) x^2 - (1 - 2/(3 c))] + (b/(2 c) x)), x]
```

> `(1/(4 a))(( 2 b Sqrt[-2 + 3 c] Sqrt[-12 + 8/c + 12 a x^2 + (3 b^2 x^2)/c^2] ArcTan[(b Sqrt[-6 + 9 c] x)/( Sqrt[2 - 3 c] Sqrt[8 c + 3 b^2 x^2 + 12 c^2 (-1 + a x^2)])])/( Sqrt[2 - 3 c] Sqrt[ 8 c + 3 b^2 x^2 +  12 c^2 (-1 + a x^2)]) + (-b Log[2 - 3 c + 3 a c x^2] +  2 Sqrt[b^2 + 4 a c^2] Log[3 b^2 x + 12 a c^2 x +  Sqrt[3] c Sqrt[b^2 + 4 a c^2] Sqrt[-12 + 8/c + 12 a x^2 + (3 b^2 x^2)/c^2]])/c)`

Comment: Removed["Int"][1/((b x)/(2 c) + 
  Sqrt[-1 + 2/(3 c) + (a + b^2/(4 c^2)) x^2]), x]